# Template tags for static content in django performance issue?

Tags: django, django-templates

We insert some static content in the admin panel. Inside our template we have a template tag that is passed the id for the content we want to display. For example {% contents 'introduction' %}

Each content section is one hit on the database. Number of such template tags is increasing. Performance is a critical issue: Under the above design: is there a way via which we can increase performance. And yet display all contents on appropriate locations?

Answer (score 1):

Use a template cache.  You would want to add this to your `settings.py`.  Just adjust the location.  This is if you would like to use `Memcached`:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

This will speed up your template loading.  Here is the official documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#setting-up-the-cache